# MySQL 5.5 partition table by A-Z

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I understand that as of MySQL 5.5, you can now partition a table by non-integer values like a varchar.  I have a table where I perform a lot of lookups on a single varchar column, hence I would like to partition on that for performance reasons.

In all instances, the value of the column is a single alphabetical word (strictly lower case a-z, enforced by validation).

What I would like to do is partition this table by the first letter in each word stored, so all words beginning with 'a' go in the first partition, 'b' in the second etc.

My gut feeling is that I could probably construct the create/alter table statement to use the LIKE statement, but am unsure about the syntax.

Has anyone done anything like this using MySQL 5.5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are determined to do it by the first letter, I think that [RANGE partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html) would do the trick.  However, if you don't have an absolute requirement for the partitioning to by by first letter, [LINEAR KEY partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-key.html) might be better.

Here is an example I lifted from the manual page sited and modified to use a varchar column:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(30),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
    separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
    job_code INT NOT NULL,
    store_id INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(fname) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('h'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('m'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('t'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

And running it:

```
... Physical database connection acquired for: Feynman
 12:33:07  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.062 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.062/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 warnings, 0 errors]
```

Comment: I don't see any syntax for RANGE partitioning with anything besides numerics and dates. I think linear key may be the only option here...

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is close to what I need, however I need it to act on a subtring of fname (the first char only), and the LESS THAN is not greedy enough as I want it to be exclusively that letter in that partition, so an equals might be more appropriate.

Comment: anything that is LESS THAN 'b' will start with 'a'.  After that, anything less than 'c' will start with 'b'.  And so on... This gets you the partitioning by first letter but still allows the query optimizer to do its thing when you are given `fname = 'albert'`.

Comment: Thanks Tom for clarifying, it makes sense now.  I will do some testing with your proposed approach tomorrow, and will post an update here.

Comment: You will also need to add the partioning column (in this case `fname`) to the primary key for your table.

Comment: Thanks Ike, I think that's doable for me (right now I have an autonumber, so that plus my varchar will still be unique).

Comment: Here is the final ALTER TABLE statement I used, works perfectly:

ALTER TABLE Tag PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(content) (
    PARTITION pa VALUES LESS THAN ('b'),
    PARTITION pb VALUES LESS THAN ('c'),
    ...
    PARTITION py VALUES LESS THAN ('z'),
    PARTITION pz VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);