# Partitioned MySQL table in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Is it possible to create a partitioned MySQL table in Django? Any example in that front will be really helpful.

Comment: For those thinking "huh, harddisk partition table?!?" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407533/mysql-5-5-partition-table-by-a-z

Comment: Are you talking about Mysql table partition?

Comment: Yes, partition of Mysql table

Answer (score 3):

I did as like the below by using sql hook of django:

1. Get SQL statement generated by django with 'python manager.py sql '
2. Copy create and alter table SQL statements of table your need to modify
3. mkdir 'sql' under your application
4. create .sql file in sql folder
5. Add SQL statement as like the below

yourmodelname.sql file:

```
DROP TABLE <table name>;

CREATE TABLE `<table name>` (
      `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      `testcase_id` integer NOT NULL,
      `databytes` integer NOT NULL,
      `direction` integer NOT NULL,
      `seconds` integer NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LINEAR KEY (id) PARTITIONS 4;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to involve Django at all. Just do [table partitioning in plain mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: jpic, do you mean 1. create a model 2. python manage.py syncdb 3. run alter command to alter created mysql DB? If that is the case then is there a way to write some hook using which syncdb will alter the table whenever a table is created from a model?